# Model Pandas Data Frame column as List of Category

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, pandas-datareader

I would like to reduce the memory output of my `Pandas dataframe`.
I am parsing a Json where some of the columns are multi-valued list of categories, such as :

`querySelectedBrands":["b1","b2","b3"]`

This is automatically inferred as an 'object' column, but ideally is a List of Category.
Whenever I have a column which is single valued categorical, it is quite simple to make the conversion :

```
interactions[col] = interactions[col].astype('category')
```

But what about a column I want to set type as a List of category ?
Later on I will encode this column transforming it in a series of Boolean columns, so I am not sure if the initial memory benefit of transforming in a list of 'category' is going to be beneficial.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, this isn't possible

Using a Pandas series to hold lists is inadvisable because it will always be of dtype `object` and represent pointers to arbitrary types. As such, operations on such a series will not be vectorisable and will have a memory overhead attached.

#### An alternative

If you have a set number of items in each list, you can split your series of lists into multiple series, see [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns). Then make each series a categorical:

```
for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```

Comment: Thanks, I am accepting this as I believe is the right answer to my question.
I am exploring this path to improve my solution !
My current problem is the following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367600/pandas-intersection-of-lists-columns